# What is causing the syntax error in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, select, syntax

Why am I getting an error from this?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read, compose, reply, moderate FROM article_permissions' at line 2
```

```
SELECT 
permission_id, category_id, group_id, read, compose, reply, moderate
FROM article_permissions
WHERE category_id = 6
     AND group_id = 0 
ORDER BY permission_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article_permissions` (
  `permission_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `compose` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `reply` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `moderate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`permission_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL. To use it as a column name in your query, put it in backticks (as you have in your table creation statement).

```
SELECT 
`permission_id`, `category_id`, `group_id`, `read`, `compose`, `reply`, `moderate`
FROM article_permissions
WHERE `category_id` = 6
     AND `group_id` = 0 
ORDER BY `permission_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

(If you enable the [`ANSI_QUOTES` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes), you can use double quotes instead, which is more portable.)

Comment: +1 for linking directly to the 5.7 manual!  You are ahead of the curve, sir.